# Jboss 6 deployment error

Tags: intellij-idea, jboss

I am having trouble starting my Jboss 6 Server, and I don't know the reason. Can anyone help?. I have all configured, and I can run it on another computer, so don't know what the problem is. This is the error I get when I try to deploy.

```
DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR:
  Deployment "jboss.jca:name=internal/cnsb/cnsb/env/jdbc/CNSBDB,service=DataSourceBinding" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:name=internal/cnsb/cnsb/env/jdbc/CNSBDB,service=DataSourceBinding',whenRequired=MapControllerStateModel$ControllerStateWrapper@2deed7a9{Installed},dependentState=MapControllerStateModel$ControllerStateWrapper@2deed7a9{Installed} **

    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1370) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.deployers.DeployersImpl.checkComplete(DeployersImpl.java:1316) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:968) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployers.plugins.main.MainDeployerImpl.checkComplete(MainDeployerImpl.java:957) [:2.2.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.deployment.MainDeployer.deploy(MainDeployer.java:383) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_45]
    at org.jboss.mx.interceptor.ReflectedDispatcher.invoke(ReflectedDispatcher.java:157) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.dispatch(Invocation.java:96) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.Invocation.invoke(Invocation.java:88) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.AbstractMBeanInvoker.invoke(AbstractMBeanInvoker.java:271) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.mx.server.MBeanServerImpl.invoke(MBeanServerImpl.java:670) [:6.0.0.GA]
    at org.jboss.system.server.jmx.MBeanServerWrapper.invoke(MBeanServerWrapper.java:138) [:6.1.0.Final]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1454) [:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:74) [:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1295) [:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1387) [:1.6.0_45]
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:818) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:303) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790) [:1.6.0_45]
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) [:1.6.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_45]
```

Answer (score 0):

verify the datasource configuration in standalone.xml file. As there is a problem with CNSBDB.